# How to validate submitted ids in Rails has_and_belongs_to_many models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app `people` can have many `projects` and vice versa.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

  attr_accessible :name, :person_ids

end 

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :people

  attr_accessible :name, :person_ids

end
```

In my `ProjectsController` I need a way to ensure that no user can ever create a `project` that belongs to another user's `people`. Right now, my select boxes can easily be hacked, e.g. through a browser console.

In my eyes, the best way to handle this is a `before_filter`. This is the one I came up with:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :valid_people, :only => [ :create, :update ]

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(params[:project])
    if @project.save
      flash[:success] = "Project created."
      redirect_to edit_project_path(@project)
    else   
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def valid_people # not working yet
      if params[:project][:person_ids].present?
        person = current_user.people.where(:id => params[:project][:person_ids]).first
        redirect_to(root_path) unless person
      end
    end

end
```

However, since I am still new to Rails I am struggling with the syntax of the `valid_people` method. How can I check if the `person_ids` belong to the user or not?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is `User` the same as `Person`?

Comment: No. A `user` can have many `people` and `projects`.

Comment: Ah.  You should post the `User` class then.  Your app's business rules aren't always going to be obvious to other people.

Answer (score -1):

It seems your use case calls for a one-to-many association instead.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end

class Projects < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

Even if it wasn't the case, the way to do that kind of validation would be through a custom validator method in your model. Controllers are not the place to perform validations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But why are you suggesting that? I mean what if a `project` actually belongs to multiple `people` or a `person` belongs to multiple `projects`? In my particular use case this is quite likely to happen.

Comment: Since you mentioned a project can't be created if it has other people different from the person who created it, I thought that's a one-to-many relationship rather than a many-to-many one. I may, of course, have misunderstood your question.

Comment: No, I just want to make sure that `User A`'s `people` can not interfere with `User B`'s `people`. The same goes for `projects`.

Comment: Since the `User` model is of such importance to your question, I`d ask you to include it in your question, preferably right above the other two ones. What you want is certainly not clear in your question as it is.